# Формат даты. Какое регулярное выражение может подойти для решения данной задачи?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Какое регулярное выражение может подойти для решения этой задачи?

**Задача:** В сообщении может содержаться дата в формате дд.мм.гггг. В заданном формате дд - целое число из диапазона от 1 до 31, мм - целое число из диапазона от 1 до 12, а гггг - целое число из диапазона от 1900 до 2012 (если какая-то часть формата нарушена, то данная подстрока в качестве даты не рассматривается). Найти все даты, которые относятся к текущему году.

Comment: _дд - целое число из диапазона от 1 до 31_ Именно от 1? или от 01? или возможны оба варианта? _даты, которые относятся к текущему году._ Номер текущего года тоже предлагается получать регуляркой?

Comment: возможны оба варианта дд. Номер текущего года тоже нужно получить с помощью регулярного выражения.

Comment: Ну и до кучи - легитимность даты контролировать надо? тип 31 апреля или 29 февраля в невисокосном году...

Comment: Да, к слову... никакая дата в указанном диапазоне годов не может относиться к текущему году...

Comment: Вряд ли, используя регулярные выражения, удастся сделать надежную и легко поддерживаемую программу. Пишите такие части на нормальном языке программирования.

Comment: И последнее. Задание вообще-то предполагает написание кода на шарпе и использование в нём регулярных выражений. А никак не получение в регулярном выражении текущего года...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JUST FOR FUN**

Регулярное выражение, которое учитывает високосные года, количество дней в месяце:

https://regex101.com/r/kegjEO/1

```
(?<![0-9.])
(?P<day>
  0?[1-9] |   # 1-9 , 01-09
  [12][0-9] | # 10-29
  3[01]       # 30-31
) \.
(?(?=0?[469]|11)(?<!31\.)|) # month of 30 day
(?(?=0?2)(?<!3[01]\.)|)     # feb not 30 31
(?(?=0?2\.\d\d(?!00)(?:[02468][048]|[13579][26]))|(?<!29\.)) # февраль високосные года и 2000 2400 2800...
(?P<month>0?[1-9]|1[12]) \.
(?P<year>19[0-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9])(?!\d)
```

Оно будет работать абсолютно корректно (если найдете ошибки - пишите), но я бы не рекомендовал использовать такое регулярное выражение, если Вы не разбираетесь в регулярных выражениях.
Всё банально: Вы не сможете исправить его, если что-то сломается. Снова придется создавать тему в форуме :)

Answer (score 0):

Я бы немного переделал вариант предыдущего оратора:

https://regex101.com/r/Lui4NG/1

```
(?<day>0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(?>.{1})(?(?=0?[469]|11)(?<!31(?>.{1}))|)(?(?=0?2)(?<!3[01](?>.{1})))(?(?=0?2(?>.{1})\d\d(?!00)(?:[02468][048]|[13579][26]))|(?<!29(?>.{1})))(?<month>0?[1-9]|1[12])(?>.{1})(?<year>19[0-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9]|[0-9]{2,4})(?!\d)
```

Comment: "предыдущий" здесь весьма относително, ссылки на участников (не ораторов) выглядят так - @ReinRaus