# регулярное выражение для даты рождения с необязательным годом рождения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, дата

```
<?php   

    /*
         входящие данные
         24.2.1989
         18.12
    */

    preg_match('/(\d{1,2})\.(\d{1,2})\.?(\d{4})?/', $inputData, $matches);

    $birthdate = $matches[3] . '-' . $matches[2] . '-' . $matches[1];
```

условие срабатвывает, но пропускает неограниченное кол-во сиволов: `18.12,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,`

Comment: добавьте `^` в начало регулярки, а `$` в конец

Comment: @mymedia сделайте ответом, пожалуйста. Поясните, почему нужно сделать именно так. Комментарии служат для уточнения, а не ответов.

Comment: Возможно будет интересно, как найти правильные даты: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/602838/481

Comment: вы должны понимать, что подобное выражение позволит ввести и дату вида `45.99.0001`

Comment: на всякий случай в пхп есть функция [`checkdate()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.checkdate.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте `^` в начало регулярного выражения, а `$` в конец. В этом случае оно не будет пропускать посторонние символы по краям строки.

- символ `^` совпадает с началом строки
- символ `$` совпадает с концом строки

Заодно ещё хотелось бы доработать, чтобы в случае указания года, точка перед ним была бы обязательной. Для этого заключим её в безымянную группу, без захвата строки.

В итоге должно получиться

```
preg_match('/^(\d{1,2})\.(\d{1,2})(?:\.(\d{4}))?$/', $inputData, $matches);
```

Comment: Ок, спасибо. Еще было бы совсем крутым, если было совпадение только с валидными датами, но это уже на Ваше усмотрение. Вопросом это не оговорено.

Comment: Тут в этом случае проще уж проверять получившийся массив `$matches`

Comment: Возможно :-) Просто я люблю всё это делать регулярными выражениями.

Comment: Все делать регулярными выражениями -  не самый эффективный способ - как в плане быстродействия, так и в плане удобства поддержки. Особенно, если учесть случаи типа 29 февраля и 31 апреля.